# How do you determine where the MySQLCPPConn library file is?

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

Consider the following Linux command to compile and run the [MySQL Connector/C++ Example 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html).

```
g++ test.cpp -lmysqlcppconn; ./a.out
```

I understand that the `-l` flag adds the specified library to the list of libraries to link, and the `-L` flag adds the specified directory to the list of directories to look in.

**Q:** Given that I did not specify the `-L` flag, how do I determine where `mysqlcppconn` is located?

My program compiles and runs without errors; however, I want to know where the MySQL Connector/C++ is installed. I've managed to find some MySQL headers in `/usr/include/` and `/usr/include/cppconn`, and there is a directory called `mysql` in `/usr/lib`, but nothing named `mysqlcppconn` is inside.

Thank you! I am re-introducing myself to developing on a Linux environment, and have lots to re-learn and catch up on.

Comment: Did you check if there's a file named `libmysqlcppconn.a`?

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. I posted your response as the answer and provided credit.

Comment: GCC uses a set of standard (default) library search paths on your system, e.g `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc.

Comment: By provided the `-l` flag as I did, am I specifying the static or dynamic object in `/usr/lib` for `mysqlcppconn`?

Comment: That depends on how `libmysqlcppconn.a` was actually build. Most probably it's a stub linking against a shared library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library file is located in `/usr/lib` and called `libmysqlcppconn`. Both a static file and shared object file exist.

This answer is provided by πάντα ῥεῖ in the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu or other debian derived system, you can use command `dpkg` with `-L` option to see installed files from deb package.

```
$ dpkg -L libmysqlcppconn7v5 
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlcppconn.so.7.1.1.9
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libmysqlcppconn7v5
/usr/share/doc/libmysqlcppconn7v5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmysqlcppconn7v5/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlcppconn.so.7
```

So the installation location for `mysqlcppconn` is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlcppconn.so`

Answer (score 0):

The command `ldd a.out` will show what libraries the executable a.out is using.